# If edges are not inserted in the deque in sorted order of weights, does 0-1 BFS produce the right answer?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

The general trend of 0-1 BFS algorithms is: if the edge is encountered having weight = 0, then the node is pushed to the front of the deque and if the edge's weight = 1, then it will be pushed to the back of the deque.

If we randomly push the edges, then can 0-1 BFS calculate the right answer? What if edges are entered in the deque are not in sorted order of their weights?

---

This is the general 0-1 BFS algorithm. If I skip out the last if and else parts and randomly push the edges, then what will happen?

To me, it should work, but then why is this algorithm made in this way?

```
void bfs (int start)
{
    std::deque<int> Q; // double ended queue
    Q.push_back(start); 
    distance[start] = 0;       
    while(!Q.empty())
    {
        int v = Q.front();
        Q.pop_front(); 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < edges[v].size(); i++)
        {
            // if distance of neighbour of v from start node is greater than sum of 
            // distance of v from start node and edge weight between v and its 
            // neighbour (distance between v and its neighbour of v) ,then change it
            if(distance[edges[v][i].first] > distance[v] + edges[v][i].second) 
            {
                distance[edges[v][i].first] = distance[v] + edges[v][i].second;

                // if edge weight between v and its neighbour is 0 
                // then push it to front of
                // double ended queue else push it to back
                if(edges[v][i].second == 0)
                {
                    Q.push_front(edges[v][i].first);
                }
                else
                {
                    Q.push_back(edges[v][i].first);
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all a matter of performance. While random insertion still finds the shortest path, you have to consider a lot more paths (exponential in the size of the graph). So basically, the structured insertion guarantees a linear time complexity. Let's start with why the 0-1 BFS guarantees this complexity.

The basic idea is the same as the one of Dijkstra's algorithm. You visit nodes ordered by their distance from the start node. This ensures that you won't discover an edge that would decrease the distance to a node observed so far (which would require you to compute the entire subgraph again).

In 0-1 BFS, you start with the start node and the distances in the queue are just:

```
d = [ 0 ]
```

Then you consider all neighbors. If the edge weight is zero, you push it to the front, if it is one, then to the back. So you get a queue like this:

```
d = [ 0 0 0 1 1]
```

Now you take the first node. It may have neighbors for zero-weight edges and neighbors for one-weight edges. So you do the same and end up with a queue like this (new node are marked with `*`):

```
d = [ 0* 0* 0 0 1 1 1*]
```

So as you see, the nodes are still ordered by their distance, which is essential. Eventually, you will arrive at this state:

```
d = [ 1 1 1 1 1 ]
```

Going from the first node over a zero-weight edge produces a total path length of 1. Going over a one-weight edge results in two. So doing 0-1 BFS, you will get:

```
d = [ 1* 1* 1 1 1 1 2* 2*]
```

And so on... So concluding, the procedure is required to make sure that you visit nodes in order of their distance to the start node. If you do this, you will consider every edge only twice (once in the forward direction, once in the backward direction). This is because when visiting a node, you know that you cannot get to the node again with a smaller distance. And you only consider the edges emanating from a node when you visit it. So even if the node is added to the queue again by one of its neighbors, you will not visit it because the resulting distance will not be smaller than the current distance. This guarantees the time complexity of O(E), where E is the number of edges.

So what would happen if you did not visit nodes ordered by their distance from the start node? Actually, the algorithm would still find the shortest path. But it will consider a lot more paths. So assume that you have visited a node and that node is put in the queue again by one of its neighbors. This time, we cannot guarantee that the resulting distance will not be smaller. Thus, we might need to visit it again and put all its neighbors in the queue again. And the same applies to the neighbors, so in the worst case this might propagate through the entire graph and you end up visiting nodes over and over again. You will find a solution eventually because you always decrease the distance. But the time needed is far more than for the smart BFS.